# Updating Internet Explorer registry keys with Visual Studio Setup Project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, installation, setup-project

On my Setup project (Visual studio 2013),
I would like to update some Internet Explorer 11 registry keys regarding the "Trusted Zone" security policies.

I did look at the "Registry on Target Machine" view but I don't think I can add/update keys that are not mine.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can add any keys you want - that shouldn't be a problem at all. There might be a concern that you are altering the internet security of the client machine, but technically there is no restriction other then the usual security rules.

Comment: I have tried that by adding keys to the destination registry path on the registry view but after the installation nothing was set. Do I need to set anything else on the project in order for the keys to be written?

Comment: Not enough detail to answer this, but it could be as simple as you having a 32-bit setup and thinking you're writing to the native 64-bit registry, which might be where you are looking. 64-bit system? Architecture of setup project?

Comment: I tried changing the installation project to 64-bit setup. I didn't find the keys either. What other information will help you?

Comment: If the registry location is restricted you need admin privileges to add or update them. You didn't say whether the keys were HKLM or HKCU.

Comment: The installation was under administrator account. The keys are HKCU.